# Error exporting SQL Server 2008 R2 database to Excel 2007

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008-r2, export-to-excel

I was trying to export SQL Server 2008 R2 database to Excel 2007. I used the export wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. I used a query to export some columns of a table. I checked the query (saw the result of parsing it) and it was good. But on the `REVIEW DATA TYPE MAPPING` it showed error notifications. It was converting `varchar` to `LongText`. But when I executed the package it failed to run showing `fail` status for steps like `prepare for execute`,`pre-execute`,`execute` . the error message is like this

> Error 0xc002f210: Preparation SQL Task 1: Executing the query "CREATE TABLE `Query` (
>   `id` Long, `sku` LongText..." failed with the following error: "Unexpected error from external database driver (1309).". Possible failure
>   reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set
>   correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established
>   correctly.
>   (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Someone has a clue whats wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Not an ideal answer (I have no idea what the cause of this problem is) but I was able to bypass this error by saving the excel sheet to 97-03 format and extracting to that.